# How to get mini games

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can someone please help me figure out how to get to mini games I don't understand it.
I want to play minigames just like [TheDiamondMinecart](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheDiamondMinecart).

Comment: Minigames on where? A Bukkit server or a Vanilla Realm?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know where to *play* a mini-game, join a server like [Mineplex](http://www.mineplex.com/) (`us.mineplex.com:25565`) or [Hypixel](https://hypixel.net/) (`play.hypixel.net:25565`).
If you want to know how to *add* a mini-game to your server, look at plugins like [CTF](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/ctf/) if you have a Bukkit server, and many other options are available for many other types of servers.

Comment: What options are avaliable? (Try Realms and LAN perhaps?)